# Journalctl : add _SYSTEMD_UNIT field into log printout

Tags: logging, docker, systemd, journal, coreos

Using the command:

> /usr/bin/journalctl -o short -f | ncat {some-ip} {some port}

To forward journal output to some remote log tracking app.

Problem is that I'm missing the systemd unit / service name in the printout making it hard to tell which service produces what log line.

for example this is a nginx line :

> Jun 25 07:51:09 localhost **bash[497]**: 10.23.132.98 - -
>   [25/Jun/2014:07:51:09 +0000] "GET /page.html HTTP/1.1" 200 321
>   "https://{ip}" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"

In the log there is **bash[497]** - the PID of the process. How can I add more data to the log ? For example the docker container name of this PID or the systemd service/unit name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end ive implemented this in a diffrent way

each service  / systemd unit has a post execute script that uses :

> /usr/bin/journalctl -u {unit name} -o short -f | sed 's/^/{unit name}/' | ncat {some-ip}
>   {some port}

now i have the unit name in the begining of the log line ! and my log collector has unit names in the message !

example

> journalctl -u **mongodb.service** -o short -f | sed 's/^/**mongodb.service**
>   /' | ncat {some-ip} {some port}

will output :

> **mongodb** Jun 26 09:11:35 localhost bash[1710]:
>   2014-06-26T09:11:35.714+0000 [rsHealthPoll] replset info
>   mongodb-0:27017 heartbeat failed, retrying

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.  `-o full` and `-o json` are no good for humans

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `-o short`, it removes information!

try `-o json` or `-o verbose`

Comment: Most log software can ingest many formats. But try verbose then. Otherwise you could pipe it through some other program to format it as your software supports.

Comment: What about humans? Monitoring multiple units with `journalctl -f -u someprefix*` works like charm, but how I add unit information?

Answer (score 1):

Python can do this:

```
from systemd import journal

j = journal.Reader()
j.this_boot()
j.add_match(_SYSTEMD_UNIT="newnginx.service")
for entry in j:
   print('{} {}'.format(entry['_SYSTEMD_UNIT'], entry['MESSAGE']))
```

(python on CentOS 7)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `_SYSTEMD_UNIT` field use the container name.

I landed here because `docker stack/swarm` is missing the `docker-compose logs` feature to log all service  on a single node.

With Docker Server Version: 18.03.0-ce and docker compose version 3.6 it is possible to send all logs to journald and log them by service name.In order to identify each container, tag them with the image name. See the logging section of docker-compose.dev.yml

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3.6'
networks:
    skynet:
    driver: overlay
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo:3
        networks:
            - skynet
        volumes:
            - /data/mongodb:/data/db
        logging:
            driver: "journald"
            options:
                tag: "{{.Name}}"
                labels: "com.docker.stack.namespace"
```

journalctl:

```
sudo journalctl -b -o short --all -f COM_DOCKER_STACK_NAMESPACE=skynet
```

Docker Command:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.dev.yml skynet
```

Will output: skynet_mongo.1.ins4s13luwiekrri3m5a8vwwl

```
Apr 24 14:23:08 c-wrk skynet_mongo.1.ins4s13luwiekrri3m5a8vwwl[19410]: 2018-04-24T12:23:08.212+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.0.0.10:36518 #3 (3 connections now open)
```

Use full notes:

To view available labels use: `docker inspect -f {{.Config.Labels}} <docker-id>`

Available tags use: [Customize log driver output](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/log_tags/)

Config journald log driver: [Docker Journald logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/)

Colorize log output: use journalctl | ccze -A

Comment: Your journalctl command is about filtering the journal. This question is about displaying logs for multiple units and showing unit names with each displayed log.